# PostgreSQL WHERE IS NULL causes bad query plan

Tags: postgresql, execution-plan, postgresql-performance, null, isnull

I have a PostgreSQL table with the following schema and indexes

```
+---------+---------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------+
| Column  | Type    | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description |
|---------+---------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------|
| number1 | integer |  not null | plain    | <null>       | <null>      |
| number2 | integer |  not null | plain    | <null>       | <null>      |
| account | bytea   |           | extended | <null>       | <null>      |
+---------+---------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------+
Indexes:
    "test_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (number1, number2)
    "test_account_idx" btree (account, number1, number2)
Has OIDs: no
```

When I query filtering `WHERE "account" IS NULL`

```sql
EXPLAIN
SELECT *
FROM "test"
WHERE "account" IS NULL
ORDER BY
  "number1" ASC,
  "number2" ASC
;
```

The query plan does not use the optimal index `"test_account_idx"`

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| QUERY PLAN                                                                    |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Index Scan using test_pkey on test  (cost=0.29..4672.97 rows=106319 width=29) |
|   Filter: (account IS NULL)                                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

However, when I filter on `WHERE "account" = <value>` instead of `IS NULL`

```sql
EXPLAIN
SELECT *
FROM "test"
WHERE "account" = '\x00'
ORDER BY
  "number1" ASC,
  "number2" ASC
;
```

The query plan DOES use the optimal index

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| QUERY PLAN                                                                        |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Index Only Scan using test_account_idx on test  (cost=0.42..4.50 rows=5 width=29) |
|   Index Cond: (account = '\x00'::bytea)                                           |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Why does filtering on NULL instead of a value make the query so much less efficient?

Comment: Did you try a an additional filtered index: `create index on test (number1, number2) where account is null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find [this thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/5e4fa822-171a-5904-46e0-28a45ff66592%40opendium.com) enlightening, if it is not by you anyway. I'll quote Tom's answer:

> You're out of luck on that.  It's true that `x IS NULL` can be matched
> to a btree index, but that's a special-case hack that is not tied into
> the logic that matches equivalence-class operators to `ORDER BY`.
>
> Generally speaking, using NULL as if it were a real, searchable value
> is a bad idea that is going to lead you to grief.  There are semantic
> gotchas with that, inherent to SQL not just PG's fault, because of
> the way they've overloaded NULL to mean a few different things.
> Because of that, we've also not worked that hard on making the planner
> super-intelligent about `IS [NOT] NULL`.  I'm not even 100% sure that
> we *could* safely optimize `IS NULL` in the same way as a normal
> equivalence-class operator is handled; but even if it's semantically
> sound, it hasn't gotten done.
>
> You might think about reserving some value such as `*UNASSIGNED*`
> for your realm column, and using that rather than NULL.  Grotty,
> I know, but less likely to have unforeseen gotchas.

Answer (score 1):

You can work around this planner shortcoming by adding the NULLed column into the ORDER BY:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT *
FROM "test"
WHERE "account" IS NULL
ORDER BY
  account,
  "number1" ASC,
  "number2" ASC;
```

It won't change the answer because all selected values will be tied on that column, but it does convince the planner to use the index.